# Symmetric monoidal structure on cosimplicial spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Is there a monoidal structure on the category $Spc^{\Delta}$ of cosimplicial spaces such that in the adjunction
$$
\Delta^{\bullet}\otimes-\colon Spc\leftrightarrows Spc^{\Delta}\colon Tot(-)
$$
the left adjoint is (strong) symmetric monoidal? 
If this is true, can it be generalized by replacing $Spc$ by any symmetric monoidal category?

Comment: If you haven't seen it, look at McClure and Smith, "Cosimplicial objects and little n-cubes, I" http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106024 . I don't think they answer your question, but they do produce monoidal structures on cosimplicial spaces, which I believe have the property that the functor $Spc\to Spc^\Delta$ sending a space to the constant cosimplicial diagram on that space is strongly monoidal.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it although I really need the Tot functor being part of the adjunction. By the way, the correct link for the McClure and Smith paper mentioned above is http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211368